# Mockito 3+ how to make mockstatic return another plain mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm migrating from PowerMockito&MockitoV2 to Mockito V3+ and trying to rewrite my tests

Previously I had a test which mocker java.sql.DriverManager class static method getConnection(...) to return a plain Mockito.mock(java.sql.Connection.class), now I'm trying to do somethins similar with MockedStatic but can't make static mock return another plain mock, have such error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue:
> Connection$MockitoMock$sLucRb7f cannot be returned by getConnection()
> getConnection() should return Connection
> *** If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on. Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
>
> 1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.    Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency
>    testing.
> 2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies -
>
>    - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.

My test code looks like that:

```
    @Test
    public void testConnectionIsOk() {
        Connection mockedConnection = Mockito.mock(Connection.class);
        try (MockedStatic<DriverManager> driverManagerMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(DriverManager.class)) {
            driverManagerMockedStatic.when(
                    () -> DriverManager.getConnection(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()))
                    .thenReturn(mockedConnection);
            boolean isConnectionOK = sut.testMethod();

            Assertions.assertTrue(isConnectionOK);
        }
    }
```

I understand the error is asking me to use a `Mockito.doReturn(mockedConnection).when(...)` but I can't pass a static method call in that `.when(...)` block

Is there any workaround for this use case or am I missing anything?

Comment: btw I have another mistake here, I imported a wrong Connection package when mocking it, not java.sql.Connection. But the answer is also valid here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `thenAnswer` instead of `thenReturn` and just return lambda expression like:

```
@Test
public void testConnectionIsOk() {
    Connection mockedConnection = Mockito.mock(Connection.class);
    try (MockedStatic<DriverManager> driverManagerMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(DriverManager.class)) {
        driverManagerMockedStatic.when(() -> DriverManager.getConnection(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()))
                .thenAnswer(invocation -> mockedConnection);

        boolean isConnectionOK = sut.testMethod();

        Assertions.assertTrue(isConnectionOK);
    }
}
```